# Which characters are permitted in django (1.4) passwords?

Tags: django, passwords

I just started working with Django 1.4 recently. I remember when I worked with 1.3 that there was a list of characters which were allowed as password characters. It included the usual alphanumeric as well as a few special characters, such as $, %, _, and @.

Does anyone know where in the documentation I can find the list of permitted password characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean [the limitation of allowed chars for username](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L67). There is no limitation on inputted password. You can use one character as long as you can input it in password input. There is [a set of chars](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L172) for making a random password, but its not the limitation.

Comment: Ah, you're completely right, I got the two confused. It explains why I couldn't find any documentation on the topic.